# Remove a Subsite which has other subsites and apps in it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sub-site

I am creating a PowerShell script to delete the subsites by importing URLs from a CSV file. The problem is that `Remove-SPWeb` does not remove a subsite having other subsites and apps beneath it. I want to delete this subsite which has other subsite beneath it.

Answer (score 3):

You should do it recursively as below

```
function DeleteWeb([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb] $web)
{
    $webs = $web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser()     
    foreach($w in $webs)
    {
        DeleteWeb($w)
        $w.Dispose()
    }

    Remove-SPWeb $web -Confirm:$false
}

$web = Get-SPWeb "http://weburl"
DeleteWeb $web
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete a site that has subsites using PowerShell, as shown below:

```
# Completely deletes the specified Web (including all subsites)

function RemoveSPWebRecursively(
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb] $web)
{
    Write-Debug "Removing site ($($web.Url))..."

    $subwebs = $web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser()

    foreach($subweb in $subwebs)
    {
        RemoveSPWebRecursively($subweb)
        $subweb.Dispose()
    }

    $DebugPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    Remove-SPWeb $web -Confirm:$false
    $DebugPreference = "Continue"
}
```

[Using PowerShell to Delete a Site with Subsites in SharePoint Server 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/05/27/using-powershell-to-delete-a-site-with-subsites-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx)

Comment: What is this GetSubwebsForCurrentUser..? Do I have add any library to run this..?